# asp.net: Code Works > Added a reference > Gets an error > Removes reference but error still occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a working piece of code. I tried adding a button click event but was getting an error. I thought that adding a reference to `System.Web.WebPages` would fix the problem but then I got a giant error saying:

> Could not load file or assembly `System.Web.WebPages` or one of its dependencies.
>  
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

So I decide to delete this reference but I'm still getting this error. Why am I still getting this error even though I removed the reference

Comment: did you try clean the solution and build again ?

Comment: Yes. I figured out the error. Even though I deleted the reference, it was still in my bin folder and it was out of date with the CMS tool I was using. I had to get an updated version and put in in my bin folder which is weird because even if I completely deleted the file from my bin folder, I would still get an error